# Unable to Import Keras (Anaconda): ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I'm trying to run Keras on Spyder (Anaconda) and I continually get this error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

Anyone else run into this problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

pip uninstall scipy
then 
pip install scipy